# lodash:Filtering Array of objects by another JSON Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, underscore.js, lodash

I am trying to filter an array of objects using lodash by another JSON Object.

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney', 'name': "donald", 'active': true },
  { 'user': 'joe', 'name': "john", 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'fred', 'name': "peri", 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'fred', 'name': "aru", 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'fred', 'name': "teena", 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'fred', 'name': "nill", 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'fred', 'name': "duck", 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'name': "resaj", 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'pebbles', 'name': "jee",  'active': true }
];
```

another json Object :

```
var searchParams = { 'user': 'ba', 'name': "don"}
```

If First array object's user contains second object's user and 1st objects name contains 2nd objects name than i want the object.I tried this code but it returns with OR condition not AND Condition.

```
_.filter(users, function(o) {
                    var checkFlag = false;
                    _.forOwn(searchParams, function(v,k) {
                        if(_.includes(o[k],v)){
                            checkFlag = true;
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    return checkFlag;
                });
```

This returns below results

```
[{ 'user': 'barney', 'name': "donald", 'active': true },{ 'user': 'barney', 'name': "resaj", 'active': false }]
```

I want only first object `{ 'user': 'barney', 'name': "donald", 'active': true }`
Any help would be appreciated.Any idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that in the iteratee function for your `_.forOwn`, if just the one of the user or name fields produces a match, then the whole user object is considered a match.

To produce your expected result, you can implement a map reduce. Replace your code with the following (this snippet uses **lodash**):

```
_.filter(users, function(o) {
    return _.map(searchParams, function(v,k) {
      return _.includes(o[k],v)
    }).reduce(function(isMatch, keyValueMatch){
      return isMatch && keyValueMatch
    }, true);
});
```

In this case, the `_.map` will check each user and provide an array or booleans telling you whether a key-value pair in `searchParams` is a match. The reduce portion will aggregate the array of booleans into a single true or false. To result in true, all the key-value pairs in `searchParams` must produce a `true` value. Otherwise, the reduce portion will return false for that user, meaning they get filtered out.

Comment: Thanks @julian soro, works like charm,tried with more than two  search params too. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `_.every()` to iterate `searchParams`, so if any check fails, the item is filtered out:

```js
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney', 'name': "donald", 'active': true },
  { 'user': 'joe', 'name': "john", 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'fred', 'name': "peri", 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'fred', 'name': "aru", 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'fred', 'name': "teena", 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'fred', 'name': "nill", 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'fred', 'name': "duck", 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'name': "resaj", 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'pebbles', 'name': "jee",  'active': true }
];

var searchParams = { 'user': 'ba', 'name': "don"};

var result = _.filter(users, function(o) {
  return _.every(searchParams, function(v, k) {
    return _.includes(o[k], v);
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```